# Code on German server parsing data correctly when run from admin page, but incorrectly when run as scheduled task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, context-user

I posted this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023408/aspose-worksheet-not-parsing-decimal-numbers-correctly-on-german-server-ignorin as well but figured I would frame it as a Sitecore question here.

I have a scheduled task that parses a .dat file as an Aspose Worksheet. It works as expected locally, but on the German server, it parses decimals incorrectly, ignoring the period delimiter. As an example, here are the logs from my local:

```
27908 10:47:59 INFO  Value: 2074.927 StringValue: 2074.927 DoubleValue: 2074.927
27908 10:48:02 INFO  Convert.ToDouble Value: 2074.927, 2074.927
27908 10:48:04 INFO  DoubleValue: 2074.927, 2074.927
27908 10:48:07 INFO  StringValue: 2074.927
27908 10:48:10 INFO  FloatValue: 2074.927, 2074.927
27908 10:48:21 INFO  StringValueWithoutFormat: 2074.9270000000001
27908 10:48:24 INFO  IntValue: 2074
```

and from the production server:

```
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  Value: 2074927 StringValue: 2.074.927 DoubleValue: 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  Convert.ToDouble Value: 2074927, 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  DoubleValue: 2074927, 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  StringValue: 2.074.927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  FloatValue: 2074927, 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  StringValueWithoutFormat: 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  IntValue: 2074927
```

You can see that both `cellInfo.StringValue` is incorrect (using periods instead of commas) as well as `cellInfo.DoubleValue` (omitting period entirely).

The issue is that **the code parses the numbers correctly when run from the admin page, as a logged in user**

Here is the scheduled task code:

```
public class DataUploader : Uploader
{
    public void Execute(Item[] items, Sitecore.Tasks.CommandItem command, ScheduleItem scheduleItem)
    {
        if (!IsDue(scheduleItem))
        {
            return;
        }

        using (new Sitecore.Globalization.LanguageSwitcher("en-US"))
        {
            var count = ImportFiles();
        }
    }
```

...and the admin page code:

```
protected void btnFtpTrialsImport_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    
      var uploader = new DataUploader();
      var resultsMessage = uploader.ImportFiles();

    litResults.Text = resultsMessage;
    
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    litResults.Text = ex.Message;
  }
}
```

both of them use the `ImportFiles()` in the `DataUploader` class.

As you can see in the `Excecute` method, I tried to set the language to "en-US", but that didn't help. I also tried logging in as the admin user within the task, but that threw an error

```
if (Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login("sitecore\\admin")){ ...
```

Why is it parsing differently when running as a scheduled task, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `Culture` of your running Thread to what you need. Sitecore's admin pages run in a specific culture context based on your logged in user; this will not be the case on a Scheduled Task.

Something like

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

And then run your `ImportFiles` method.

Comment: Thank you!!! That fixed it